# How can I fill more text in preference's summary field?

Tags: android, text, android-preferences

How can I fill more text in preference's summary field? 
Is there a way to expand summary field size?

[image]

P.S: There is already rather small font size, so I don't want to make it supersmall.

Comment: Use unicorns, as they tend to use less space compared to ponies... (more seriously, you seem to be asking how to put more text in the same space without making the font smaller..? Sounds like you need some form of magic...)

Comment: @Veger Best solution will be to increase space, but I don't know how to...

Comment: You can try to decrease the margin/padding at the left or right, or increase the height of the field. But I doubt whether that is possible when using the Android Preference API. On the other hand you seem to have 4 lines of text, maybe your description is just too long...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've done it that way:

1. Created layout xml for my preferences

2. Pasted there content of [PATH TO ANDROID SDK]/platforms/android-[VERSION]/data/res/preference.xml

3. Deleted line `android:maxLines="4"`

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to show your XML layout so I can know how you are setting the field's height.  There are many ways to do this.

You should either increase the layout_height attribute, change the outer layout to a ScrollView, decrease the layout_weight attribute, set layout_height to "wrap_content", etc...